# how to get from string two operators and operand in java?

Tags: java, string

do I need to get two operators and an operand between them from a string in the range 1-10?

```
public class Main {
public static String calc(String input) {
    String [] operands = input.split("[+-/*]");
    int op1 = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
    int op2 = Integer.parseInt(operands[1]);
    String [] op = input.split("[0-10]");
    return "";
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    calc("19-10");
}
```

}

Comment: What do you think `input.split("[+-/*]");` and `input.split("[0-10]");` do?

Comment: that `return "";` may not be a good idea

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround would be:

```
public class Main {
   public static String calc(String input) {
    String [] operands = input.split("[+-/*]");
    int op1 = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
    int op2 = Integer.parseInt(operands[1]);
    //op3 is your input value but without the first number
    String op3 = input.split(operands[0])[1];
    //op4 is your input value without the first and last number
    //op4 would be "-" in your case
    String op4 = op3.split(operands[1])[0];
    return "";
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
    calc("19-10");
   }
}
```

A better solution would be:

```
public class Main {
   public static String calc(String input) {
    String [] operands = input.split("[+-/*]");
    int op1 = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
    int op2 = Integer.parseInt(operands[1]);
    String[] ops = input.split("\\s*[0-9999]+");
    //ops[1] will be "-"
    return "";
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
    calc("19-10");
   }
}
```

Search for "Java Regex example". I can't explain it that easy.